# Type, Name, value in godaddy firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I created a firebase hosting called abcd-1c8d2.firebaseapp.com

bought a domain in godaddy (abcd-sample.com)

Now, how do I configure the DNS in godaddy for CNAME?
What should be value of name, and value? I believe the type should be CNAME, name should be what? wwww or abcd-sample.co and value should be abcd-1c8d2.firebaseapp.com?
I tried, it's not working.

Comment: @Yvette Firebase website says ask question on Stack overflow so people will keep on asking firebase related questions here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried with `CNAME` but it's not work, I used `A records` and it work now:
Add two more `A records` on your godaddy with

### A records 1:

```
Type: A records
Host: abcd-sample.com
Value: 151.101.1.76
```

### A records 2:

```
Type: A records
Host: abcd-sample.com
Value: 151.101.65.76
```

Check images below for details:

### Firebase Config:

[image: Firebase Config]

### Godaddy Config:

[image: Godaddy Config:]

Comment: Why CNAME is not working?

Comment: I don't know the reasons here, I just try with option 2 by `A records` and it's work for me.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me as well. Appreciate you hep.

Comment: Can confirm this. Just solved the same problem. CNAME does't work, A record works. Don't know if godaddy or firebase's problem though.

Comment: Having similar issues here. Did you delete the default A record that comes with GoDaddy? If you don't you end up having 3 which I don't think is right, is it?

Comment: @HuyNguyen Shouldn't there be a check mark on "GO LIVE" in the firebase console? my site works on desktops but doesn't load on mobile phones, which is very weird and I'm breaking my head trying to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @EmptyCup My site still working well on mobile.